# Bootstrap 4 - Input group append with checkbox and label

Tags: bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am able to add the checkbox and label inside the input-group, though as seen in the image, the padding is off.

[image]

using pl-4 it's better, but not right.

[image]

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <%= ff.remove_nested_fields_link fa_icon('trash-alt', type: :solid, class: 'icon-trash') %>
    </span>
  </div>
  <%= ff.collection_select(:store_id, Store.all, :id, :label, {}, {class: "custom-select"}) %>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <div class="input-group-text pl-4">
      <%= ff.check_box :manager, class: "form-check-input" %>
      <%= ff.label :manager, class: "form-check-label" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

For `Bootstrap v4.3.1` you can use the following ... `form-check-input ml-0`, `form-check-label ml-3`

```
<div class="input-group-append">
    <div class="input-group-text">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-0" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label ml-3" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a `form-check-inline` layout inside the `input-group-text`. Check it out:

```
<div class="input-group-text">
     <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input">Option 2
          </label>
      </div>
 </div>
```